What can I expect for US grad admissions with a degree from a reputable Middle East university?
My university, the American University of Beirut has consistently been ranked as one of the top universities in the Middle East, excluding Israeli universities.
I am concerned about how US profs view the academic rigor of Middle East Universities. What can I expect for US grad admissions with a degree from a reputable Middle East university? My field is computer science.

The American University of Beirut certainly used to be well known, I'm not sure how that may have changed over the last few decades. So, you should expect pretty much what any applicant expects - you might get accepted and you might not based on the actual application.

Your university is well known. You might give preference to universities that have faculty or previous students from there. Most American universities now use third party evaluations of foreign transcripts and the quality of the programs when reviewing applicants. I have read many of these and found them to be realistic evaluations.

Doctoral programs are pretty good at being able to learn about the reputation of foreign universities, having dealt with them frequently. And note that in the US, you don't need to have come from a world famous (or nationally famous) university to gain admission. It depends more on what you have done than the name recognition of your university. And, there are probably enough Lebanese faculty in US large universities that word of mouth will give an idea.
I'd think you can expect to be treated fairly and evaluated honestly. Expect a lot of competition, however, so nothing is certain.
Note that letters of recommendation are especially important here and if your letter writers are established academics with good reputations, you should be considered along with any other international student.
A complicating factor, of course, is the general "unrest" in Lebanon and surrounding countries. If that has affected the general quality of the higher educational system it could be an issue. I have no knowledge of that, but it is probably discoverable.
I doubt that you have issues of language, but that can complicate things for some people.
See the US answer for the canonical question on doctoral admissions to learn of the process here. How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in Country X?. Unless you are independently wealthy, you will also probably want to apply for a Teaching Assistantship, which will fund your education and provide a modest living stipend. CS departments need a lot of TAs to support the undergraduate program.

Well, yes, the various kidnappings, murder, and car bombings in, roughly, the 1980s, had major impacts on the number of (mostly US) visiting or permanent professors at AUB. Not sure of the situation there now, although https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_University_of_Beirut suggests there are now financial issues as well.

"there are probably enough Lebanese faculty in US large universities" Really? Perhaps they're more common in CS but I have never met a Lebanese faculty member (or grad student).
